# How to keep postgres read only permissions if pandas replaces the specific table?

Tags: postgresql, pandas

I'm reading an existing table, concat a new dataset, remove duplicates and write the updated table back into the database.

I have the situation that if I'm using this string:

```
df.to_sql('xxx', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

given read-only permissions (read-only) are beeing dropped and only the database owner  user keeps his access to the table.

I'm using pgadmin4 on postgres 11, but I think my problem may be based on the 'replace' keyword or the access management in the database.

Do you know that issue and how to do it better?

I want that given permissions for an existing table are not beeing dropped when replacing it.

Comment: The solution is ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES.

Comment: Sorry, but could you please explain what that mean exactly? I've tried ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO user;

Doesn't work :( I still lack the permission to open it.

Comment: Ok. In theory it will only affect newly created tables from then on. But I did so 5 minutes and sadly it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you add the commands you tried and how you determined that it doesn't work, I could help.

Comment: I found a topic which is discussing that issue as well. Do you think it might relate to fact that I'm trying to alter default privileges of a user instead of a group? Before any additional trouble shooting I would start to setup the role management correctly by defining a reader group, alter its default privileges and add that specific user to that group instead of alter the permissions directly on user level.

Comment: Ok, so. The error stays the same. I've created a user_group for readers and configured the reader_user as a member. The user_group has altered defauled priviliges in the specific schema for beeing able to select all tables. If I replace the table with my python script above or drop the table before and write a new table in the schema, the user_group cant access it (permission denied for table xy). If I grant access manually via GRANT SELECT .... it works, but stops working when the table is beeing replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yay, I found a solution based on the given hint. It's:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE table_creating_user in SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO read-only;
```

while read-only can be a user- or group-role. But it's important that the table_creating_user is explictly named, because the user - not his granting group - will be owner of those tables.

Comment: Ah, I see you figured it out. Good for you!